# How to link a file on a Mac?

Tags: macos, ratchet-bootstrap

I'm using the library [Ratchet](http://goratchet.com), and it makes you download the files onto your computer. I have a Mac, and I never learned how to link to a file *on* the same Mac.

So, what I'm asking is, how do you link to a file on your same mac?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "link to a file".  If you're talking about a file system level link, you should use the `ln -s` command from a terminal to create a soft link to a file.

More details about `ln -s` can be found at http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/tasks/links2.2.1.html

Comment: There is a file in my downloads folder, and I'm trying to link to it in my code.

Comment: The file is `ratchet-2.0.2-dist (1).zip`

Comment: double click on it to unzip it and copy (drag and drop) the files to your local project directory

Comment: My entire project is online. I don't have a local project directory. In windows, you do it as file://.../..., is there something like that on mac?

Comment: file:///Users/<your username>/.... will work on Mac too.  But your project will only work when used from your local laptop, your users will not be able to link to these file.  These files should be uploaded and serve from your server.

Comment: I'm not looking to publish this. This is only a test project to fiddle with ratchet